# Wordpress undefined function get_footerhome()

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I'm trying to help someone fix a problem with their wordpress site. The home page uses a different footer however calling it gives his error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_footerhome()

I'm at a loss for what the problem could be. The file exists and there are no spelling errors. It's in the same directory as index.php and the get_footer() works.

Any help would be great.
Thanks,
Nick

Comment: Does `get_footer('home');` work?  I assume your file's called `footer-home.php`

Comment: There is no function named `get_footerhome()` in Wordpress. It possibly mean `get_footer('home')`

Comment: There's a file named footerhome.php no hyphen. I didn't make the website so I'm not quite sure how it was setup before the footer broke. get_footer('home'); loads the footer that is on every other page but not the one that is specific to the home page.